# VS code doesn't resolve junit test

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit

I've made java project on vs code and now I'm trying to run junit tests but vs code sees there's something wrong.I've installed JUnit JAR Downloader ,Java Extension pack and Junit Testfile Generator, but the problem still exists as the image shows.
Error says: package org.junit does not exist

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: package org.junit does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is caused by the incorrect placement of the package. We can put the package in the part shown in my picture to solve it.

[image]